# create alpha channel colormap via image grayscale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I will like create a alpha channel, for explanation I put a  example:

Here I have a color map

```
theCM = plt.get_cmap('temperatura')
theCM._init()
```

I created a linespace with number of colors of the cmap and put them in the alpha channel

```
alphas=np.sin(np.linspace(0, 1, theCM.N))
theCM._lut[:-3,-1] = alphas
```

It is posible control more and create the alpha channel from a picture, for example you segment gray scale width , take a value of a pixel and and create the alpha channel.

Thank you and sorry my bad english